# What is the brand or type of this track lighting fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

It only has two contacts, like J or L types, but they are staggered, like H type fixtures.[image: track head photo]

Comment: Tony, please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what's expected of users when they've been provided a satisfactory answer.

Comment: is there anything printed on any of the parts?  .... lousy picture by the way.

Answer (score 1):

With the offset it’s likely a 2-circuit track.

I can’t tell from the picture, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_lighting) suggests measuring 7/8” vs 1” might yield a clue. (but the article is inconclusive and doesn’t list all types).

Most electrical supply houses have a box of short track pieces and track parts under the front counter for comparison and matching.

OP has determined he has Juno (type J) 2-circuit track this info, which was originally supplied in comments.